# Bootstrap Datetimepicker issue occured

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

```js
$('body').on('mouseover','.input-append',function() {  
  var $grid = $("#hire_rate");
  var data = $grid.pqGrid('option','dataModel.data');      
  var rowIndx = this.id.substring(this.id.length,this.id.length - 1 );
  $('#datetimepicker'+rowIndx).datetimepicker({
      format : "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm",          
      pickSeconds : false, 
  });
```

```html
<div class="input-append date" id="datetimepicker'+rowIndx+'" data-date="" data-date-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm">
<input type="text" value="'+data[rowIndx].from_date+'" id="fromdate'+rowIndx+'" style="width:160px;height:16px;width:140px;size:12px;font-family:Arial" readonly><span class="input-append add-on">
<i data-date-icon="icon-calendar" data-time-icon="icon-time" class="icon-calendar"></i></span></div>
```

I am using version 3 of the Bootstrap datetimepicker. Here without selecting date in a calendar, if I click outside, it is displaying current date and time in textbox.

How can I resolve this issue? I don't want to display the current date and time. After selecting date in a calendar only I want to display the selected date and time in textbox.

`useCurrent: false` is not working in version 3. How can I do this?

Comment: Clarified and fixed formatting issues; consider including some more code and being more specific about what you want.

Comment: The only problem I am facing,without selecting any date in calendar also it is taking current date and time. I want after selecting date only the selected date should be displayed in the textbox.

Comment: How can I display after selecting the selected  date in textbox?